# Using Google API, can I retrieve sections of a doc based on headings?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-docs

I have a doc that I read the text from and insert to my webpage. This doc is expanding to cover multiple areas and I would like to try and make the process more efficient since my webpage is a single page application. Currently I get the entire doc using this

```
async function printGoogleDoc(docID, apiKey){
await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${docID}/export?mimeType=text/plain&key=${apiKey}`)
.then(function(res) {
    return res.text();
}).then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
}).catch(function() {
    console.log("error");
});
}
```

Then I read through it and sort the content for the webpage with JavaScript.

I would like to improve performance a little by just using google api to get sections of text based on their headings if possible.

Something like

```
async function printGoogleDoc(docID, apiKey, heading)
```

and it would return all text under that heading and stopping at the next.

But how would I do this? Is there a way?

To further the example here is the layout of the potential Google Doc:

## h1 Some Title

### h2 sub title

content
...
end of content

### h2 second sub title

other content

I am using fetch since there is no need for a user to log in with google and no need for authentication since the content is pulled and displayed on the webpage.
Is there a way to only grab only the content under "h2 sub title" and ignore the rest?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your situation. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike I have updated the question with an example of the doc and data I wish to obtain. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Google recommends using their libraries (code) to access the Google Docs Service.

> we recommend that you use the Google-provided client libraries.

You are not using Google code to interact with the Docs Service. You are using the standard REST API.

Assuming you want to use the REST API, there does exist the concept of a `document` that is returned. This is not the Document Object Model (DOM) document but is a Google crafted "document" that is explained in [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#header) which includes a `header` property. However this header refers to header and footer sections of a page and not heading styled content (or HTML header elements H1-H6).

Long story short, it's doable. I would "download as" `webpage` from Google Docs using the REST API. Do this by setting the `mimetype` to `text/html` in your REST call.

Then, use a basic tool such as JSDOM's CSS selectors (via `document.querySelectorAll`) to get at the headings and  adjacent content with something like [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).

Comment: This was helpful. I was trying to avoid getting the entirety of the doc so that load times would be faster but this seems like a good solution as well. I may also just create another doc so that all the content is not all in one place since it is content for different areas of the webpage.